# miniKanren F# with FSLogic

Tags: f#, minikanren

Well I'm following a tutorial of [`miniKanren`](http://minikanren.org/) in `scheme` using [`FsLogic`](https://github.com/kurtschelfthout/FsLogic), but I just got stuck in this example

```
(run 1 (q)
 (== '(lambda (x) x) '(lambda (x) x)))
```

And I'm writing it in `f#` like this:

```
run 1 (fun q ->
        (fun x -> x) *=* (fun x -> x)
       )
```

But it fails (doesn't compile) :(
[image]

Reading the tests I tried to use [`project`](https://github.com/kurtschelfthout/FsLogic/blob/master/FsLogic.Test/RelationsTest.fs#L192) but it doesn't work either (I'm not really sure what project does yet).....

I'm following this ["uncourses"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCuVTGWNU3s&index=1&list=PLO4TbomOdn2cks2n5PvifialL8kQwt0aW) from the [`minikanren`](http://minikanren.org/) homepage

Comment: "Doesn't compile" is not a good description of a problem. Please show error messages and/or other undesirable results you're getting.

Comment: Ok, added and image showing the error message

Comment: How is `( *=* )` defined?  It looks like it's defined in such a way that the first argument can't be a function.

Comment: here it's the definition of `*=*` https://github.com/kurtschelfthout/FsLogic/blob/master/FsLogic/Goal.fs#L158 it works with all the other samples like `x *=* z &&& 3Z *=* z &&& q *=* x` the question is not `f#` generic (i think) it's about how to convert the `scheme` code using `miniKanren` to `f#` using `FSLogic` a port of `miniKanren`

Comment: @jjchiw - I don't have any experience with FsLogic, but it appears to me that the first argument to `*=*` must be a value of type `Term<_>`, so you can't just use a function there.  But without knowing anything about minikanren or FsLogic I'm afraid I can't advise you on how to construct an appropriate value of that type.